# Java Streams Create a Map from another map

Tags: json, java-stream, collectors

I am trying to translate a JSON payload into another format, the request is something like

```
{ "k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3","k4":"v4"} //this is stored as input
```

The translated request should look like

```
{"input_batch":[{"value":"v1"},{"value":"v2"},{"value":"v3"},{"value":"v4"}]}
```

ATM I am doing it

```
List<Object> input_batch = new ArrayList<>();
input.values().forEach(v -> {
   Map<String, String> tmpMap = new HashMap<>();
   tmpMap.put("value", v);
   input_batch.add(tmpMap);
});
```

Is there a better way of doing using Collectors please? this appears to be an odd mapping, my research did get any leads

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a the `.map()` method followed by a collector, or java17's `toList()`:

```
Map<String, String> data = Map.of("k1","v1","k2","v2","k3","v3","k4","v4");
record Value(String val) {}


@Test
void test() {
    List<Value> inputBatch = data.values().stream().map(v -> new Value(v)).toList();
    Map<String, List<Value>> newMap = Map.of("input_batch", inputBatch);
    System.out.println(newMap); 
}
```

If you don't want another class for the `Value` you can use maps - same as in your example - by changing the .map() method to `.map(v -> Map.of("value", v))`, but I would stay away of using maps where they aren't really needed.